# Auto-populating dynamic text for attribute table information on multiple layers within MXD with Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, dynamic-text

I am working on creating a maintenance inventory for a City's Parks Departments in ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop. I have used the Township/Range/Section boundaries as the clipping areas for my data driven pages to set up viewing windows for different areas of the City. I have created 5 shapefiles of landscape maintenance types, which are present at varying levels in each of the individual Sections within the City. I have set up my pages as follows in the attached image, and would like to know if there would be a way to auto-populate the "table" at the bottom of the page with information that is only present in the current viewable Section(s).

[image]

For each of the 5 landscape maintenance types, I have the total area and modes 1-3 in the attribute table. Is there a way to auto-populate the red circled areas for just data within the individual page based on this?

I have found through researching this issue (without much luck so far) that more than likely I will have to join my tables for each landscape type with my index layer that is determining the data driven pages.

If this is the case, what would be the best method to join my landscape maintenance layers with the index layer?

I have access to the X-Tools extension if it would be helpful in this instance.

Comment: To do this I think you will need to use ArcPy to clone text and graphic elements to create a pseudo-dynamic table as described in the duplicate.

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate, and thanks for the link. I'll use that for more detailed information.